# Is it possible to config docker-compose to ignore error of one their services and continue others?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wonder if we have an option to configure `docker-compose` to ignore errors of one of the containers and continue to start others.

For example, here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
  redis:
    image: redis
```

If redis container fails to start, the web container still start.

Comment: ...and why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sound silly, but I want to bypass the duplicated containers, which have the same name.

Answer (score 11):

The only way I know of to do what you are asking is a bit ugly:

Bring your services up one at a time, ignoring any errors:

```
docker-compose up -d web || true
docker-compose up -d redis || true
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse, seem like that's the only thing that I can do.